# Performance Impact when using multiple angular apps in one application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a web application using nodejs and angularjs.
For each page in the application, I have a .js file containing an angular app for that page.
Currently, I have a total of 17 Apps for 17 pages.

I want to know if there's any downside to doing this, as opposed to having one large app, and creating controllers for each of the pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worrying about this before you have your app finished is [**premature optimization**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Angular.js [**do have support**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) for several applicationson the same page, I believe that it is highly unlikely that they would supposed this if it was devastating for the performance.

EDIT: I obviously misunderstood your question about the several applications.
I do not think that there is any technical downside to split the application as you do, but again, you can always refactor this at a later stage if it happens to be a problem.
Get your site up first, worry about technicalities like this later!